# JSON to String in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, array, json

I have the following method to convert JSON to a String

```
// Convert the JSON-encoded image info into an array
$image = new JRegistry;
$image->loadString($this->item->image, 'JSON');
$this->item->imageDetails = $image;
```

But this code works only on an object. Is there any way to use these functions on an array?

Comment: From a shallow dig into the source code, it looks to me that the conversion only goes from object to string and string to object.  Did you want to `json_decode($this->item->image, true)`, then use `->loadArray()`?

Comment: Oh sure, thank you @mickmackusa

Comment: Is this what you are seeking to do? It works as you require?  Shall I post it as an answer?  Do you actually need it to be loaded into the registry?

Comment: Actually i'm retrieving from the db and i wanted to follow along with the function above using the same function - but for arrays - to retrieve the image and its atributes; the probem is that i'm using array instead of object so i was trying to figure out how to obtain a similar result; therefore, your solution works perfectly; thank you once again. Before asking the question, though, i managed to implement a solution using json_decode in the default.php but the original function is placed in the model and i haven't used loadArray() but it's working all the same. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Perhaps I'll leave this question to be answered by some of the regulars here who have a far more intimate understanding of best practices within Joomla.

Comment: I see but it works, that's what matters, even tho it's not what we would call "best practice". Thank you